# Can't debug or run windows console app written in c# - Access is denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've just installed Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition and wrote a simple console app hit **F5** to debug it, I am getting this error:

[image]

When I try to run the exe directly, I get this error:

[image]

This is rather strange; this never happened to be before. Any ideas?

I am using Windows Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299 and .NET 4.6 SDK.

---

I thought the issue was with my application code; so to rule this out, I made another console app with hello world and even this is erroring like above:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong but this seems so likely a permission problem. Did you run Visual Studio with Administrator rights?

Comment: Try creating your project on a different path (I.E. the default path in documents\Visual Studio 2017\Project)

Comment: @Steve I am going to try that now.

Comment: @JoshPart Tried that and it didn't help.

Comment: @Steve Same error when I tried to run visual studio as administrator.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/894433/you-may-receive-an-access-is-denied-error-message-when-you-try-to-debu this is kinda outdated but it could be helpful

Comment: I came across, when I searched this error, unfortunately I can't seem to do this on windows. https://i.imgur.com/zPb9obn.png (I can't see the `Local Security Policy`).

Comment: go to control panel and select VS2017 and select the option under add/remove applications, `Repair` reboot also see if there is an update for that as well, to run as administrator.

Comment: @MethodMan tried that, no luck.

Comment: Just a wild guess: disable your AV before launching Visual Studio and try to run your project.

Comment: I tried disabling my AV and it hasn't helped. But something strange happened, when I turned off my WIFI/Internet, i could run the exe :s